Using ffmpeg to steer zoom effect with audio levels?
Is it possible to animate a zoom effect dynamically based on audio levels in some fairly easy way? I looking for a kind of "beat-detector-effect". Can It be done in one pass, ie without writing out levels to a file, then read the file and build the animation manually?
